# flink Table SQL Api

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I want to know can we write query using two tables ( join) in flink Table and SQL api.

I am new to flik, I want to create two table from two different data set and query them and produce other dataset.

my query would be like `select...  from table1, table 2...` so can we write like this query which querying two tables or more?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink's Table API supports join operations  (full, left, right, inner joins) on batch tables (e.g. those created from a `DataSet`).

```
SELECT c, g FROM Table3, Table5 WHERE b = e
```

For streaming tables (e.g. those created from a `DataStream`), Flink does not yet support join operations. But the Flink community is actively working to add them in the near future.